# unable to print the data after encoding in swift

Tags: swift

I'm getting below error when i try to encode the data. If i print directly without encoding its printing properly

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

```
   // get the NSURLRequestSession and get the data
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(nsurlReq){
        (data,response,error) in

        // check whether there is no error

        if(error==nil)
        {


           // println("Data \(data) ");
            var encodedData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!;

            println(encodedData);


        }

    } // 

    // you need to resume the task

    task.resume();
```

Comment: Then the data does not contain a string in valid UTF-8 encoding. Perhaps the server encodes in  a different encoding? Or it is binary data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that your data has invalid encoding and that is why you're not able to print out the parsed data.

Comment: I'm using var url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&gl=in&tbm=nws&authuser=0&q=london")   not sure about the encoding mechanism

Comment: Try to set the encoding to `NSASCIIStringEncoding` as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059405/nsurlconnection-asyncronous-request-returns-null

Comment: Thanks Steffen..after changing to NSASCIIStringEncoding, it worked